# Unable to get the variable in sqlite query Phonegap

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

Please have a look. I am getting an error of "Uncaught type error: can not read the property 'title'".

here is how code looks like :

```
db.transaction(function(transaction) {
                                       transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO post_details(post_title, post_date,post_comment,post_content,post_categories,post_image) VALUES ("'+data.posts[i].title+'","'+data.posts[i].date+'","'+data.posts[i].comment_count+'","'+data.posts[i].content+'","'+data.posts[i].categories+'","'+data.posts[i].thumbnail_images.full.url+'")',[],  nullHandler,errorHandler);
});
```

This "data" is a variable holding JSON data which i am calling through AJAX. Which is returning properly if am normally alert it.

Thank you!

Comment: May be its single quotes problem in your insert query.

Comment: I tried both. But not working.